# SQL Group By condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have following SQL query for start:

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN CAST(tDate as DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() as date) -- if older then Today
           THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))        -- assgin yesterday's date
           ELSE CAST(tDate as date)                           -- use the date
       END as tDate, 
       SUM(tDuration-ISNULL(tDone,0)) as tToDo FROM tTable 

    WHERE .....conditions.....

    GROUP BY tDate   
    ORDER BY tDate
```

I have two problems with that:

I tried to `SUM()` all of the past task's duration to yesterdays date, which I succeed, but `GROUP BY` wouldn't sum them into one date, it leaves them at separate lines. I don't know why, when I cast datetime input to date and they should have equal value.

I tried to use `CONVERT` instead of `CAST` and to separate the `CASE` processing into sub-query with no improvements.

Comment: For item #1, if you want to group without the time component then you need to have that logic in your `GROUP BY` as well. Otherwise, you're telling SQL to split them into groups by the entire `tDate` - which it then faithfully does. Also, which RDBMS are you using? Please tag it.

Comment: Tom, this is correct, I somehow forgot about that. Tested and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your query with this:

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN CAST(tDate as DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() as date) -- if older then Today
           THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))        -- assgin yesterday's date
           ELSE CAST(tDate as date)                           -- use the date
       END as tDate, 
       SUM(tDuration-ISNULL(tDone,0)) as tToDo FROM tTable 

    WHERE .....conditions.....

    GROUP BY CASE 
           WHEN CAST(tDate as DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() as date) -- if older then Today
           THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))        -- assgin yesterday's date
           ELSE CAST(tDate as date)                           -- use the date
       END   
    ORDER BY tDate
```